# Logical redirection apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, redirection

I'm trying to install a Rails app on company.com/myapp.
How I tell Apache to ignore "myapp" from the request string  ?

Thanks,
Mickael.

Edit: it does not seems possible wih Rails (Strange!).
So I've ask my admin to setup myapp.mydomain.com for me.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you should be able to use

```
Alias / /myapp/
```

In your apache configuration but this won't trick your application in spitting out the correct links.

So a request to
`http://example.com/myapp/where/i/want/to/go`

could also be written as
`http://example.com/where/i/want/to/go`

But the links presented to the UA would still be looking like
`http://example.com/myapp/where/i/want/to/go` if the application itself does not handle this.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. My application is still getting the request but with /myapp in the query string.